# Docker containers unable to comunicate

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have 2 containers that belongs to the same network:

```
version: '3'
services:
  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: ./website
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: travellist
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    ...
    networks:
      - app-network

  administration:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: travellist
    container_name: administration
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    environment:
      ....
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    container_name: webserver
    image: nginx:1.17-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8000:80
      - 7999:81
    ...
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

as you can see the two applications runs over NGINX over 2 different ports... however, I'm unable to send a request from one application to the other one... non of the following works (from administration, that is the one that works over `81:7999`):

```
localhost:80
localhost:8000
app:80
app:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

From the `administration` container you should send your request to the `webserver` on port `80`.

From the `administration` container, you can first check that you can `ping` the `webserver`, if it succeeds it means that the two can reach each other on the network and for this reason, you can execute your request.

Please note that the port `8000` is only exposed to the host machine.

Comment: I got it working with `http://host.docker.internal:8000`... in case of problem, I'll try your solution, +1 in the meantime